# SMS Rest API Using WSO2- ESB

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, jsmpp, wso2-esb

I want to write a Rest API to **Send SMS, Receive SMS, Get Notification, Subscribe SMS Notification and Un Subscribe SMS Notification** using WSO2 ESB 4.8 or new version.

1. I checked [WSO2-ESB-Sending SMS block](http://mytecheye.blogspot.com/2013/01/wso2-esb-sending-sms-alerts-for-failures.html), It contain only **sending SMS**, but not  **Receive SMS, Get Notification, Subscribe SMS Notification and Un Subscribe SMS Notification**.
2. Also can someone guide me how to implement the rest of the part (E.g SendSMS is void method in axis2-transport-sms-1.0.0.jar, Its mean we wont get the response after calling SendSMS method. So how can check the response status?

Thanks

Comment: Please check on [this](https://gayanlggd.wordpress.com/2014/12/19/sending-a-message-from-smsc-simulator-to-wso2-esb-using-smpp-transport/) which explained how to simulate SMS receiving with WSO2 ESB using smsc simulator.

Comment: @Reka Thanks for update, but its copy of Isuru's Tech Thoughts :)